# Wait for all component rerenders

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple component with a custom hook. If I add that hook `useTest`(as I see this hook uses Context and gql queries) I got about 6 rerenders of this component and see flickering on h1. Is it possible to wait for all renders and only then render the h1? Thanks.
`

```
import React from 'react'

const AccountDetail = () => {
  console.log('RENDER!!!', new Date())
  const { test } = useTest()
  return <h1>{new Date().getMilliseconds()}</h1>
}

export default AccountDetail
```

`

Comment: I guess it is due to your custom hook. You should only return the test when gets some result. Your hook might be throwing multiple renders. Can you please show the hook?

Comment: Don't render ***date*** inside your JSX. Store is in state. Or maybe you can use meno hook
 ```js
const currentTime = useMemo(() => {return new Date().getMilliseconds()}, [test])
```

Comment: It's increase a little bit performance

Comment: What does `useTest` do to cause re-renders?  Does it produce some observable state that you can use to conditionally return a result from this component?